# Getting SNAP(AOP), Autofac and ASP.Net MVC 5 working together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, aop, autofac

I'm trying to get Snap (https://github.com/TylerBrinks/Snap) to work with MVC 5 and Autofac to be able to use attributes in controller's actions.

I've been able to make a console app work according to the examples, but when I try it in MVC I can't seem to be able to make it.

The problem is that the LoggingInterceptor doesn't get called.

This is what I've done:

Configure both Autofac and Snap

```
public static class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureAndSetContainerAndAop()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var autofacContainer = new AutofacAspectContainer(builder);

        SnapConfiguration.For(autofacContainer).Configure(c =>
        {
            c.IncludeNamespace("WebUI.Controllers.*");// Here, if try c.IncludeNamespaceOf<MvcApplication>() I get a NullReferenceException.;
            c.Bind<LoggingInterceptor>().To<LoggingAttribute>();
        });

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(autofacContainer.Builder.Build()));

    }
}
```

Attribute and Interceptor.

```
public class LoggingAttribute : MethodInterceptAttribute
{
    public LoggingAttribute()
    {

    }
}

public class LoggingInterceptor : MethodInterceptor
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggingInterceptor");

    public override void InterceptMethod(IInvocation invocation, MethodBase method, Attribute attribute)
    {
        Logger.Info("Executing LoggingInterceptor.InterceptMethod()");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }

    public override void BeforeInvocation()
    {
        Logger.Info("Executing LoggingInterceptor.BeforeInvocation()");
        base.BeforeInvocation();
    }

    public override void AfterInvocation()
    {
        Logger.Info("Executing LoggingInterceptor.AfterInvocation()");
        base.AfterInvocation();
    }
}
```

And the controller with the attribute:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Logging]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods you wish to intercept (`Index` etc.) should be `virtual`, see [here](http://kozmic.net/2009/02/23/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-vi-handling-non-virtual-methods/)

Comment: Did using virtual methods fix your issue in this case?

Comment: Using virtual is the answer.